# How to get file size of newly created Image() if src is base64 string?

Tags: javascript, image, coffeescript

How can I get the size of the newly created `new Image()` in bytes if this image's `src` is `base64` data image?

I have such coffeescript code:

```
# This string is received after some original image preprocessing
base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64......"

newImageObj = new Image()
newImageObj.src = base64String
newImageObj.onload = ->
  console.log "Resized image width is " + this.width
  console.log "New file size in bytes is " + newImageObj.fileSize
```

The output is always like this:

```
Resized image width is 500
New file size in bytes is undefined
```

This `newImageObj.fileSize` is always `undefined`.

Comment: In _Base64_, `4` chars represents `3` bytes and `=`s on the end let you know how many bytes short the final _String_ (so you don't carry `0`s)

Comment: It is sad that there is no built-in method for this, however, your approach works, so thank you :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is the algorithm to find file size from base64 string:

```
base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64......";

var stringLength = base64String.length - 'data:image/png;base64,'.length;

var sizeInBytes = 4 * Math.ceil((stringLength / 3))*0.5624896334383812;
var sizeInKb=sizeInBytes/1000;
```

Comment: very close :) 1024

Comment: What is the significance of the constants you are using 4, 3 and 0.5624896334383812?

Comment: I think var sizeInKb=sizeInBytes/1000; should be var sizeInKb=sizeInBytes/1024;

Comment: Can you explain why  0.5624896334383812 ! ++ @paul-s

Comment: In case, you want the result in Mb, so → var sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / 1048576; Thanks by the way

Comment: This formula is right for the wrong reason and thus overcomplicated. Base64 encodes 3 bytes of binary data on 4 characters. So to get the size of the original data, you juste have to multiply the stringLength (minus the header) by 3/4. The answer above made the mistake of multiplyijng by 4/3 instead. The 0.5624896334383812 magic constant is there to correct that error (4/3 * 0.5624896334383812 = 3/4).

Comment: The real formula is thus Math.ceil(stringLength / 4) * 3, minus 1 or 2 bytes if the string length is not a multiple of 4 or if it ends with padding, if you want to be extra precise. 1 missing char or one = at the end: 1 byte to remove. 2 missing chars or == at the end: 2 bytes to remove. It cannot have 3 missing chars or ends with ===.

Answer (score 8):

I'd personally use something like this to do the above, which will work correctly in the case that the data isn't formatted correctly (eg, an '=' missing, which usually gets decoded correctly anyway)

```
new Buffer(base64String, 'base64').length
```

Comment: What is `Buffer`? I can't find any reference for this. Only `ArrayBuffer` exists, but it doesn't expect the arguments you've provided.

Comment: Ah, this is Node. Was looking for a front-end solution. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you have any trouble importing Buffer, you may want to check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877890/14766155

Answer (score 2):

**You can refer to this example and see how base64 decoding works:**

---

I have also attached the reference to base64 table.
[Base64 index table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0fCW.png)

Decoding->base64 string : QWJoaXNoZWs=

---

1. First, you need to split the string character by character. Thus, you got 12 groups:
   Q
   W
   J
   o
   a
   X
   N
   o
   Z
   W
   s
   =
2. Each group (character) is a Base64 character that has its own index, and now your task is to convert groups to indices. To do this, by mapping values from the Base64 Characters Table replace each character by its index (if you cannot find an index for a specific group, just discard it). All in all, you should get the following indices:
   16
   22
   9
   40
   26
   23
   13
   40
   25
   22
   44
3. At this step you should convert each group from decimal to binary. So find corresponding decimal values in the ASCII table and make sure you get the following binary values:
   00010000
   00010110
   00001001
   00101000
   00011010
   00010111
   00001101
   00101000
   00011001
   00010110
   00101100
4. Now remove the prefix “00” (two zeros) in front of each group:
   010000
   010110
   001001
   101000
   011010
   010111
   001101
   101000
   011001
   010110
   101100
5. There you have a simple concatenation of previous groups (that is, glue all the binary values together and get an 66-character string):
   010000010110001001101000011010010111001101101000011001010110101100
6. Then, divide the resulting string into groups so that each one has 8 characters (if the last group has less than 8 characters, you must discard it). Now you have 8 groups of eight-bit bytes:
   01000001
   01100010
   01101000
   01101001
   01110011
   01101000
   01100101
   01101011
7. Once again using the ASCII table, convert all binary values into their ASCII characters:
   A
   b
   h
   i
   s
   h
   e
   k
8. The final chord, concatenate all ASCII characters to get the result string:
   Abhishek

Thus,

**Size of original string(in bytes) = floor(6n/8) – padding**

---

**Size of base64 string(in bytes) = ceil(8n/6) + padding**

---

**When decoding from base64**

```
int paddingCount = (base64Data.endsWith("==")) ? 2 :(base64Data.endsWith("=")) ? 1 : 0;

double dataSize = floor(base64Data.length() * 3 / 4) - paddingCount;
```

**When encoding to base64**

```
int paddingCount = 3 - (stringToEncode.length()) % 3;

double dataSize = ceil(stringToEncode.length() * 4 / 3) + paddingCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the question here, and maybe I'm wrong but...

Looking at your code above, it looks like you are defining a function and using arrow notation to return the answer. However, there are TWO lines following the arrow, and they aren't grouped in any way, so... the arrow notation is returning the value of onload() to the first log() only. So "this" actually has a value. But the second log() is a new command altogether, right? It's not being returned from onload(). So newImageObj is undefined.

Or maybe it's a coffeescript syntax, I'm not familiar with it. Would this fix it?

```
newImageObj = new Image()
newImageObj.src = base64String
newImageObj.onload = ->
{
  console.log "Resized image width is " + this.width
  console.log "New file size in bytes is " + newImageObj.fileSize
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take advantage of the inner workings of `fetch` for that:

```js
const url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64...'
const resp = await fetch(url)
const size = +resp.headers.get('Content-Length')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const img = 'data:image/png;base64,aBdiVBORw0fKGgoAAA';

const buffer = Buffer.from(img.substring(img.indexOf(',') + 1));

console.log("Byte length: " + buffer.length);
console.log("MB: " + buffer.length / 1e+6);
```