# Getting error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, typescript1.8, typescript1.4

I am trying to do base64 encode in NodeJS using TypeScript.

Following code working fine in JavaScript.

When I am writing same thing in TypeScript and compiling, I am getting Buffer is not find error.

```
var base64Policy = new Buffer(stringPolicy, 'utf-8').toString('base64');
```

Can someone help me to do same thing in TypeScript.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add this line at top:

```
declare const Buffer
```

and it should compile without errors.

Declarations is required to use node built in libraries or other global objects, you can manually declare it like above.

With new version of Typescript, you can also use official declaration files:

```
npm i -g typescript@next
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

for other libraries, install `@types/library_name`.

more details: [Improve Declaration File Acquisition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9184), [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: I guess this would be apt - `npm i --save-dev @types/node`. Dev dependencies!

Answer (score 70):

For the IONIC 4 developers, I installed it using
`npm install --save @types/node`
When I tried adding `"types": ["node"]` as shown below

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
},
```

to the 
`tsconfig.json`
it did not work. I had to add the entry to
`tsconfig.app.json`
Please refer to the following link for relevant documentation.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1271#issuecomment-291658668
Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Well, that didn't work in an Angular 12 app. Installed the types, added to tsconfig.app.json, but still seeing "Buffer is not defined" in the browser console :/

Comment: @danwellman if you found a solution, can you provide it here please ? :D

Comment: Node's Buffer class doesn't exist in a browser context, so web frontends need to use a different approach. One such approach is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540058/7023816

Answer (score 30):

**Prologue**

[Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) is part of the [Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/). Because TypeScript doesn't know classes from Node.js by default, you will need to install [declaration files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) (type definitions) for Node.js.

If you see the following error, you will have to install type definitions manually:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.

**Installing Type Definitions**

You can install type definitions using the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool. I will show you how to do this:

1. Install the `typings` tool with npm:

   `npm install -g typings`
2. Install type definitions for Node.js from the [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) (`~dt`) repository:

   `typings install dt~node --global --save`

The typings tool will create the following directory "`typings/globals/node`" and link it in "`typings/index.d.ts`". There will be also a file called `typings.json` (because of the `--save` option), which references the resolved type definitions:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

Note: If you see the error "typings\globals\node\index.d.ts(71,26): error TS1110: Type expected", then your Node.js definition is too recent. The typings tool has [issues with latest type declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/8514). In such a case, just check the version in your `typings.json` file. For me `node#6.0.0+20160621231320` was working but `node#6.0.0+20161212163245` was not.

3. Now all you have to do is adding `index.d.ts` as a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) within your code (which uses the `Buffer` class):

*YourClass.ts*

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

export class YourClass {

  private static toString(encoded: string): string {
    return new Buffer(encoded, "base64").toString();
  }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

With the [release of TypeScript 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/) a new type definitions system has been announced.

You can now forget about the `typings` tool. All you need to do is running this command to install [TypeScript definitions for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node):

`npm install --save @types/node`

Please also make sure that you have the following entries in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ...
  ]
}
```

P.S. If you need type definitions for other classes (than included in Node.js), you can search for them here: http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Comment: I've been fighting this for days and this is the first time I've seen a solution that actually works with a windows 10 environment. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, as nice as this is for fixing my windows environment issues it broke OSX environments. ;( 

Getting a typescript error:

Typescript Error
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'extensions' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeExtensions'.

Answer (score 20):

For Angular users:

1. Run the following command

`npm install --save @types/node`

2. In your `tsconfig.app.json` file, add these two lines to the CompilerOptions:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me, but how these instructions are resolving the issue??

Answer (score 17):

Buffer is from `Node` namespace. First install

`npm install --save @types/node`

then add below code to your `tsconfig.json` file inside the `compilerOptions` section

```
"types": ["node"],
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

The `typeRoots` entry specifies a list of directories for type definition files to be included. It requires *TypeScript* version 2.0 or later.

Comment: Installing @type/node `npm install --save @types/node`, wasn't suffice. I had to add `"types": ["node"]` to my `tsconfig.json`. Thank you

Comment: I followed all the steps, but still getting the error

Comment: I found the solution, (I am using Angular), the `src/tsconfig.app.json` has to be updated rather than `tsconfig.json`, here is a reference to the issue in Github: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1271#issuecomment-320352814

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue in Karma/Jasmine

1. Run

`npm install --save @types/node`

2. In your `tsconfig.spec.json` file, add these two lines to the CompilerOptions:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    //...
        "types": [ "jasmine" , "node" ],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I wanted to use `Buffer` with typescript in a browser context, the only solution for me was to install the [`buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) package.

```
npm install buffer
```

And then, in the file where you want to use it,

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer/';
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for an Angular project!

Comment: How to import using require in a nodejs project. Becasuse import statement can only be used inside module

Comment: Lifesaver! Not sure why that trailing slash is important, but it is. Without the slash worked in Node, but failed in Bun.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me.

```
npm i -S @types/node
```

Then in tsconfig.json

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "types" : ["node"]
    ....
}
```

https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/adding-types-node-to-angular-84a629976c86

Comment: With angular 17 this works shiny