# cannot find name 'Buffer' in ionic app when integrating 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, tsconfig

[image]

> cannot find name 'Buffer' in ionic app when integrating 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

Comment: Please provide the relevant context.. Read [mcve]

Comment: Generally, questions are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:

> You actually need to add "types": ["node"] to the tsconfig.app.json
>   file that the angular-cli creates in the src directory. By default,
>   types is an empty array.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1271#issuecomment-291658668

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue including `amazon-cognito-identity-js` into an Angular 4 app.  Basically Typescript doesn't understand these Node types (Buffer, http, stream, fs, etc...).  To understand why, we need to look to [how Typescript specifies packages to include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If typesRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.  for example:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

> This config file will include all packages under ./typings, and no packages from ./node_modules/@types.
>
> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included. For instance:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express"]
   }
}
```

> This tsconfig.json file will only include ./node_modules/@types/node, ./node_modules/@types/lodash and ./node_modules/@types/express. Other packages under node_modules/@types/* will not be included.

Hate to copy/paste basically the answer but I can't really word it any better than the docs.

Check if `"typeRoots"` and/or `"types"` are defined in any of the `tsconfig.json` files (angular-cli projects have `./tsconfig.json` and `./app/tsconfig.app.json` files).

If `"typeRoots"` is defined, ensure `"node_modules/@types"` is included.  If `"types"` is defined, ensure `"node"` is included.

To include all @types, remove the `"typeRoots"` and `"types"` from the `"compilerOptions"` altogether, but keep in mind, this might create conflicts between different type declarations, so the best option is to probably have `"node"` included in the `"types"` property.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but there is no typeRoots or types defined in the tsconfig.json file. Anyone ever find an answer to this?

Comment: If you're having this issue, it means the typescript compiler doesn't know about the basic Node types that installed node_modules rely on.  If neither `typeRoots` or `types` are defined, all @types folders are included.  Ensure `@types/node` is installed as a devDependency (`npm i -D @types/node`) and try recompiling.

Comment: I've tried that. The issue is that the place where the types are missing is within the aws-sdk node_modules folder. Whats strange about this is that it seems to work fine on any OSX system, but has this error on any Windows 10 system I try. I don't understand why there would be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple different things that seemed to contribute to this issue. Thanks to Benny Neugebauer for his answer on this post: [error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875401/error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-buffer)

The key pieces I found to resolve this was to do the following.

1. Use the stable release of NodeJS and not the newest release
2. Install the typings tool with **npm install -g typings**
3. Install Type definitions with **typings install dt~node --global --save**
4. Verify you don't have these types installed as they cause issues with the only solution I've found to make both Windows and OSX work. **npm remove @types/node**
5. Remove your node_modules folder and rebuild with **yarn**
6. add reference path to **app.component.ts**

   ```
    /// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

    export class YourClass {
   ```

After doing this everything worked. This was the only solution that worked in a Windows 10 environment and an OSX environment. My final tsconfig.json file looks like this FYI

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```