# Error TS2688: Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (1, 23)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using VS2019.

I have created an Asp.Net Core 3.1 web app.

I am trying to use the latest version of signalR.

i am following the steps outlined here:

[Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

I have done this:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and select Add >
  Client-Side Library.
- In the Add Client-Side Library dialog, for Provider select unpkg.
- For Library, enter @microsoft/signalr@latest.
- Select Choose specific files, expand the dist/browser folder, and
- Select signalr.js and signalr.min.js.
- Set Target Location to wwwroot/js/signalr/, and select Install.

I attempt to build my project and I get these errors:

[image]

I google on this:

```
Error TS2580: Build:Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` visual studio
```

The best match I can find is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875401/getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-buffer
```

I try to implement this (know it is not correct for me but want to see where it takes me :) )

[image: I am stuck!]

I am stuck!