# General usage of js built-in libraries in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to use crypto module of node.js in an Angular project and I guess I am missing something.

In a normal js file (ts too) I can directly import crypto module like below.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
```

But in Angular, I can't access that directly. I had the same problem with Buffer module and I have solved it by installing "@node/types" and made some changes on tsconfig.app.json and polyfills.ts file.

I also can find crypto module under "@types/node" and import it too (ide finds the source files). But when I try to use a method under it throws "ReferenceError: process not defined"

How can I solve this problem and what is the proper way to use built-in js modules in Angular 8?

Comment: have you installed it the types package @types/crypto-js ?

Comment: I have tried installing it but I am also dependent to "fernet" library which it is using built-in crypto too and I don't have an alternative for that library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875401) is a good example.

Basically, I have installed **"@types/node"** and added extra lines below to `tsconfig.app.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
}
```

Then I have added these extra lines below to `pollyfills.ts`

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer =  global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = global.process || require('process');
```

Answer (score 0):

install the types package of crypto-js (`@types/crypto-js`) and import the module like this

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";
```

Comment: As I recall crypto-js library is not the same library and I am using another module (fernet) which it is directly dependent to crypto