# Laravel - How to get the image content size?

Tags: php, laravel, image

The data the user is sending is not an image file but its content. How can I get its size without making it a file and use `filesize` and something similar?

The content of the image as an example:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASwCAYAA......`

Is it possible to create a formula to calculate the size of the image content? something like `strlen($imageContent)`.

Comment: Did you try `base64_decode` after  `base64,` and retrieve the length of that decoded string?

Comment: I tried it after you said. I tried `mb_strlen(base64_decode($imageContent))` and it returned `2075849` however the size of file is `416 KB (426,720 bytes)`.

Comment: take a look at JavaScript based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750491/3584881) and try to convert it into PHP

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `8bit` encoding on `mb_strlen`:

```php
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASwCAYAA......';
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

$size = mb_strlen($data, '8bit');
```

Comment: What didn't work? I just tested it, it does work in my case.

Comment: And I just tested it too. The image size is `416 KB (426,720 bytes)` but the returned value of the `$size` is  `2763849`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file and then rapidly deleted.

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASwCAYAA......';
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);

$size = getimagesize('/tmp/image.png');
unlink(/tmp/image.png);
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want to create a file and get the size. While I want to get the size only by content.

Comment: with unlike the file will be deleted after you get the size